# Upload script in php

Tags: php, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to do File Upload in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270261/unable-to-do-file-upload-in-php)

I am trying to learn to write file upload script in PHP. I don't know why this doesn't work. Please have a look

---

```
<?php
$name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];

if(isset($name)) {
    if(!empty($name)) {
        echo $name;
    }
    else {
        echo 'Please choose a file';
    }
}
?>
```

---

It gives an error message `Notice: Undefined index: file in`

---

The html part is

---

```
<form action="submissions.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

---

I am using wamp on Windows. What may be the cause for the error ?

Comment: The clue is in the error message. The index 'file' doesn't exist in the FILES array. At a guess because you have this code before you've sumitted the form?

Comment: what does `var_dump($_FILES)` say? does it contain any files at all?

Comment: @JonStirling: Yeah.. I have the php code before the html form part. Can this be a problem ?

Comment: This sure is, because your array index is non-existent at this time. Try executing this code when you uploaded something.

Comment: According to what @JonStirling has figured out, you probably just need to put your PHP code inside an if-block: `if ($_POST["submit"] == "Submit") { //do stuff }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error message. The index 'file' doesn't exist in the FILES array. At a guess because you have this code before you've sumitted the form?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the form was submitted before executing your PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] === "Submit") {

    if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        if(!empty($name)) {
            echo $name;
        }
        else {
            echo 'Please choose a file';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You'd still have the same problem as the OP if the file input field wasn't set in the form.

Comment: @JonStirling: How so? Did you see my recent edit to check `isset($_POST["submit"])`? *edit*: oh, nevermind, I see what you're talking about. Answer updated.

Comment: Tbh, I'm now totally confused. You may have been completely right. I can't remember off the top of my head if the empty file element still gets sent in headers or not. If it is (which it could well be) then your previous code was perfectly valid. Long day is loooong :P Somebody else may be able to clarify :)

Comment: I honestly don't know either if it is sent when it is left blank. But even if `$_FILES["file"]` is set, I would bet that `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` would still be an undefined index if it were left empty.

Comment: + 1 for a) being as confused as me b) working example

Answer (score 0):

check if it exists first,

```
if(isset($_FILES['FormFieldNameForFile']) && $_FILES['FormFieldNameForFile']['size']>0){ # will be 0 if no file uploaded
```

then check your use of the field components.

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']  # The original name of the file on the client machine. 
$_FILES['userfile']['type']  # The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted. 
$_FILES['userfile']['size']  # The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file. 
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']  # The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server. 
$_FILES['userfile']['error']  # The error code associated with this file upload
```